# Facebook API not working well

Tags: javascript, facebook, api

Just tried to embbed a login button in html page  with Facebook JavaScript API

```
<body>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=637150723035739&version=v2.0";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="medium" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false"></div>

</body>
```

I just get nothing as an output 
I don't know what i am doing wrong

Comment: look here, read about the error message when clicking the button. http://jsfiddle.net/wuk6s/

Comment: Yes that's normal but i don't even have the button as an output

Comment: could you provide more info where this button is located, what is the rest of the site? I just copied your code to fiddle, and it works.

Comment: OK no more stuff just tryed to launched the above file in firefox

Comment: works on all browsers...

Comment: Yes I don't know what i a doing wrong .

Comment: Where did you tried to use that script? inside an existing html?

Comment: Ah just have exactly the same code in a an html file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook/Google Login API's needs a specific App [Domain](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDUQFjAB&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name&ei=ERKUU8ShFsu3uASd7YGwCQ&usg=AFQjCNFbsxYJS5-AvzITxtkb55d52nX0Zw&sig2=nCVnsSdANw2VX_otnwea0A&bvm=bv.68445247,d.c2E) from which your app should call the FB API functions. If not, it would simply not work as is in your case.

From [Aknurm.com](http://ankurm.com/labblog/using-localhost-for-facebook-app-development/):

> All you need is, a Facebook account and [WAMP server](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http://www.wampserver.com/en/&ei=VBKUU4qrBsO1uATbsILIAg&usg=AFQjCNFO33ha831rcBcg26auReVm9E2Dtw&sig2=i4S-j_hH_YoVqLsGWFIjvg&bvm=bv.68445247,d.c2E) running on
>   your PC. Steps are quite simple.
>
> ## Enable curl extension
>
> By default on WAMP curl is disabled. In order to communicate with
>   Facebook server you need to enable it. All you have to do is, Start
>   your WAMP server then (left) click on green WAMP icon from system
>   tray, navigate to PHP then PHP extensions and then check php_curl. You
>   might need to restart your WAMP server to take effect.
>
> Create a folder for your app on your PC.
>   = Once you are done with enabling curls, you need to create a folder on your PC for your Facebook app. You can choose any name for it.  In
>   simple, create a new folder named `fb` inside your www folder of WAMP
>   server. Then test it by navigating `http://localhost/fb` . You must
>   see all your app content here.
>
> ## Create app on Facebook
>
> Once you are done with above two steps, you are now ready to create an
>   app on Facebook. Just navigate to Facebook developer’s website and
>   then from apps menu select Create New App.
>
> Then Facebook will ask you for basic information about your app. You
>   can choose any desired name and email address but you have to fill
>   `localhost` as `App Domain` and `http://localhost/fb` as `Website with
>   Facebook login`. This will enable login from localhost.

[image]

Comment: http://ankurm.com/labblog/using-localhost-for-facebook-app-development/ You're been a busy little plagiarist, haven't you?

Comment: @AugustusFrancis - That's still not good enough. If you copy the words of another, you *must* blockquote them to indicate they are not your own. I've done this in the above, but simply throwing in a link is not acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

The Problem seems to be, that you have this code in a html-file on your local machine (e.g. Desktop) then it does not work. I tried it.

You have to run this html on Web-Server  eg. XAMPP for testing purposes.

Here is a Link to XAMPP: https://www.apachefriends.org/de/index.html

Notice: if you new to web-design, a lot of code does not work without a server, direct run files works only with plain HTML, most of all other code (JS,PHP,...) only works with a server.